# Different functions for calculating phase/argument of complex numbers

Tags: python, numpy, phase, cmath

Are there any differences between the

```
cmath.phase()
```

function from the `cmath` module, and the

```
np.angle()
```

function from `numpy`.

Comment: `cmath.phase` won't work on a numpy array to start with...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematically, there is no difference between these two functions. Both compute the phase or argument of a complex number as:

```
arg = arctan2(zimag, zreal)
```

See documentation for [`cmath.phase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html#cmath.phase) and source code for [`numpy.angle`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6a58e25703cbecb6786faa09a04ae2ec8221348b/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2136). From software point of view, as @Julien mentioned in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576732/different-functions-for-calculating-phase-argument-of-complex-numbers#comment88162927_50576732), `cmath.phase()` will not work on `numpy.ndarray`.